# Reducing Build size of VR project

Tags: unity-game-engine, gear-vr, virtual-tour

I am building a 360 Virtual tour for Samsung GearVR using Unity 5.6.
I want a high resolution image to be seen in the GearVR to get a good experience to the end user so i didn't compress the original photosphere image and also set the resolution to 8192 in import settings in unity.This gives a high resolution and clear picture in GearVR .

But the problem is that the image which I have clicked is just of 5.8 MB and after importing without compression it became 64 MB.
This is adding up to my Application size. Since it is a virtual tour I will have to import many such pictures which is then eventually going to be a huge sized application which is not good.

I tried compressing it in unity import settings but that gives me a low resolution(blurry ) image in GearVR.

Is there any solution through which I can get a high resolution image as well as less app size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Resolution to 8192 and compression quality to high quality and check crunch compression in unity import settings of image to reduce the application size during build.
We will get high resolution image and the application size won't be too large.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have great resolution and high user impact in your Unity project, then you have to encounter with high application size.

You can set the same quality options to reduce the file size of your application via;

```
Edit->Project Settings->Quality
```

[image]

Also, [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html) are some ways for reducing the file size of your build.

Comment: Thanks.These quality settings are must for high resolution but crunch compression helps dealing with application size.